# Question with Legend and Ordering x-axis in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I am having two frustrating problems (fairly new to r!).

1. I am trying to order the x axis by Feature, based on the order in my df. When I use scale_shape_manual(labels = c("196", "176", "194")), the graph gets very wonky.
2. I am trying to fix my legend. I would like for it to list "196", "176", "194" in order rather than 15, 16, 17. When I use scale_fill_manual I get the error message: Warning message:
   `guides(<scale> = FALSE)` is deprecated. Please use `guides(<scale> = "none")` instead. I don't know of another way to manually change text in legends.

```
df <- data.frame(Feature = c(196, 176, 194),
                 NISP = c(65.26548673, 64.09090909, 72.16494845),
                     Bio = c(18.53298346,   10.68950428,    54.19047619),
                     MNI = c(30, 35, 58))
               
library(ggplot2)
 

Graph <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Feature)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = NISP), color = "black") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = MNI), color = "black") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Bio), color = "black")+
  geom_point(aes(y = NISP, shape="16", size=2))+
  geom_point(aes(y = MNI, shape="15", size=2))+
  geom_point(aes(y = Bio, shape="17", size=2)) +
  ylab("Percentage") + ggtitle("Percent MNI, NISP, and Biomass") + 
  guides(color = FALSE, size = FALSE)

Graph
```

Comment: If variable Feature is categorical value, then you have to specify that: `Feature = as.factor(c(196, 176, 194))`

Comment: To reorder x axis, use `aes(x= fct_inorder(Feature))`

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot2` works best with data in "long" form, while you're having some issues because your data is in the "wide" format. Things get easier if we use `tidyr` to switch to a long format, and I believe it resolves the issues you're having:

```r
df <- data.frame(Feature = c(196, 176, 194),
                 NISP = c(65.26548673, 64.09090909, 72.16494845),
                 Bio = c(18.53298346,   10.68950428,    54.19047619),
                 MNI = c(30, 35, 58))

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Feature) %>%
  mutate(Feature=factor(Feature, levels=unique(Feature))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Feature, y=value)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=name)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=name), size=2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 15, 17)) +
  ylab("Percentage") + ggtitle("Percent MNI, NISP, and Biomass")
```

[image]